# Javascript and Wordpress: Functions.php for a child theme to change a value on a JS file

Tags: javascript, wordpress, themes

In wordpress...I created a child theme. Now I want to edit/change a value in main.js file. This file is part of the parent theme.

As far as my research goes, I need to copy the file main.js into the child theme, folder js/main.js, and make the change there.
Then, I need to add a file "functions.php" with code that deregister's the original main.js file in the parent theme, and redirect it to my main.js in the child theme's js folder. correct?

Every website I found online explaining this situation, was showing a very short description of the code for the php to deregister/dequeue and then register/enqueue the new file.
**Could anyone please write down the simplest functions.php file I need in order to have this done?**

**From the parent functions.php**

> wp_register_script('main', JS_URI . '/main.js', 'jquery', false, true);
>
> wp_enqueue_script('main');

**From  js/main.js**

I'm only looking to change "play: 10000" for "play:1000

```
$(function() {
$('#slides').superslides({
  animation: "fade",
  play: 10000,
  slide_easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
  slide_speed: 800,
  pagination: true,
  hashchange: false,
  scrollable: true
});  });
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your functions.php file:

```
<?php

wp_dequeue_script('main');
wp_deregister_script('main');

wp_register_script('main', YOUR_CHILD_THEME_JS_URI . '/main.js', 'jquery', false, true);
wp_enqueue_script('main');
```

Make sure to change `YOUR_CHILD_THEME_JS_URI` to your child theme's JS path.

You can use [`get_stylesheet_directory()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory) to get the path to your child theme folder since [`get_template_directory()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory) would return the path to the parent theme, and not your child theme.

Comment: "You can use get_stylesheet_directory() to get the path to your child theme folder". I'm not sure what you mean. where should I use get_stylesheet_directory? Also, When I try to change YOUR_CHILD_THEME_JS_URI in Dreamweaver, I get an error. I'm replacing it with just /js. To be honest, I'm not 100% sure what URI is other than the same as URL.

Comment: How does this look like? '<?php


define( 'CHILD_DIR', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() );

wp_dequeue_script('main');
wp_deregister_script('main');

wp_register_script('main', CHILD_DIR. 'js/main.js', 'jquery', false, true);
wp_enqueue_script('main');

?>'

Comment: It did not work. I give up though. All this time spent just to change a value in a javascript file...Wordpress is not for me. I found so many limitations. Like, as far as I can tell, there's no way to work directly on code, other than on the wordpress editor, AND is all PHP. Thanks anyway though.